# createListItem with SP.ClientContext in for each loop

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, client-side-rendering

we use a custom aspx page in SharePoint 2013 to create list items in a for each loop via sp.js - works fine!

```
function PushValuesToList(results) {

results.forEach(function(entry) {

    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', createListItem(entry.Bestellmenge)); //makes sure sp.js is loaded and then calls createListItem method

});
 }

function createListItem(Menge) {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('AnforderungenSAS');

var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

oListItem.set_item('BenMenge', Menge);

oListItem.update();

clientContext.load(oListItem);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
);
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

console.log('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());

 }

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
   //error
    }
```

Problem is that when I create three items in via the loop it returns the following ids:

```
Item created: -1
Item created: 235
Item created: 235
```

Instead of the right ids from the list.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Code seems fine,something wrong in the way loop is called. 


    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', createListItem());

function createListItem() {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('AnforderungenSAS');
for(count = 0; count < entry.Bestellmenge; count++){
var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

oListItem.set_item('BenMenge', Menge);

oListItem.update();

clientContext.load(oListItem);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
);
}
}
```